# Preg_split matching more than what it should

Tags: php, regex

Code:

```
    $pattern = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
    $urls = array();
    preg_match($pattern, $comment, $urls);

    return $urls;
```

According to an online regex tester, this regex is correct and should be working:

http://regexr.com?35nf9

I am outputting the $links array using:

```
$linkItems = $model->getLinksInComment($model->comments);
//die(print_r($linkItems));
echo '<ul>';
foreach($linkItems as $link) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

The output looks like the following:

- http://google.com
- http

The $model->comments looks like the following:

```
destined for surplus
RT#83015
RT#83617
http://google.com
https://google.com
non-link
```

The list generated is only suppose to be links, and there should be no lines that are empty.  Is there something wrong with what I did, because the Regex seems to be correct.

Comment: You should post `$model->comments`

Comment: @MarkLakata Thanks, that probably would help. I have edited it in.

Comment: That regular expression is a Godforsaken atrocity and I'm not surprised you can't make heads or tails of it; for reasons of maintainability and basic sanity, you would be extremely well advised to find *any other method* of splitting up `$comment` into the values you need.

Comment: Why don't you simplify your regex to something like "https?:(\S+)". That will probably cover your bases.

Comment: @MarkLakata Using that what I get returned is the same as before, though the http(S) part of the links are gone.

Comment: `split` is the wrong function. It throws away everything that matches, and leaves everything else. You want something else. I'm not a PHP guy, so I don't know what the equivalent is.

Comment: `preg_match` gets matches and puts them into an array - is that what you want?

Comment: @aaron miller how else do you suggest matching valid urls? i assume that regex is just copypasta from some site. it's not a big deal if he can't understand it because he'll never need to change it.

Comment: @sgroves His match target appears to be multiple lines separated by newline, so can be handled by a split and a much simpler regex, as detailed in the answer I'm about to post.

Comment: @AaronMiller Be advised, the text will always be different. I am just trying to parse text and look for a links and then display links in a list. The data given to the function could be one long line with normal text plus multiple links.

Comment: @Fogest That rather invalidates my answer, and would've been good to mention in the question; it's not unreasonable to assume that the example given of comment text actually exemplifies comment text. In any case, as long as you can guarantee that URLs in the comment text won't contain literal spaces (as can be accomplished by URI-encoding links on their way into the comment text, assuming that's an option), then `/((?:http|ftp)s?\:/\/[^ ]+) /` should serve to match them. If you lack sufficient control over your comment text to ensure that URLs in it are encoded, then God help you.

Comment: @AaronMiller My question gave example text, this is what one of the cases looked like. I am essentially trying to parse user inputted text and output links in a list.

Comment: @Fogest The point I'm making is that nothing in your question suggests that differently formatted cases of comment text exist, and that that would've been a useful thing to mention. As for the substance of the problem, the suggestion in my previous comment stands; I'll modify my answer to incorporate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding right, you should use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) in your `getLinksInComment` function instead:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $comment, $matches);

if (isset($matches[0])) {
    return $matches[0];
}
return array();    #in case there are no matches
```

`preg_match_all` gets all matches in a string (even if the string contains newlines) and puts them into the array you supply as the third argument. However, anything matched by your regex's capture groups (e.g. `(http|https|ftp|ftps)`) will also be put into your `$matches` array (as `$matches[1]` and so on). That's why you want to return just `$matches[0]` as your final array of matches.

I just ran this exact code:

```
$line = "destined for surplus\n
RT#83015\n
RT#83617\n
http://google.com\n
https://google.com\n
non-link";

$pattern = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $line, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

and got this for my output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "http://google.com"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "https://google.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "http"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "https"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented this, please check my edit to see the new code. Problem is now the output is still not correct. It only took part of the second URL.

Comment: @fogest is `$model->comments` a string with newlines? you may need to use `preg_match_all` instead

Comment: The $model->comments is user inputted so it very well could. Using _all presents me with a list that now has three "Array" items. So it looks like ` *Array * Array * Array` Pretend each Array is a new bullet on a new line.

Comment: sorry, got confused while working on this. see my updated answer - think it does exactly what you need

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought _all just meant it would act like a global search, did not realize it returned a multi dimension array. I simply switched my return to `$urls[0]` instead of just `$urls`, and it now works! Thank you! Accepted + Upvoted.

Comment: great! also updated my answer to reflect that. (yeah, i forgot that little fact about `preg_match_all`)

Answer (score 0):

Your comment is structured as multiple lines, some of which contain the URLs in which you're interested and nothing else. This being the case, you need not use anything remotely resembling that disaster of a regex to try to pick URLs out of the full comment text; you can instead split by newline, and examine each line individually to see whether it contains a URL. You might therefore implement a much more reliable `getLinksInComment()` thus:

```
function getLinksInComment($comment) {
    $links = array();
    foreach (preg_split('/\r?\n/', $comment) as $line) {
        if (!preg_match('/^http/', $line)) { continue; };
        array_push($links, $line);
    };
    return $links;
};
```

With suitable adjustment to serve as an object method instead of a bare function, this should solve your problem entirely and free you to go about your day.

Comment: Check my comment I made to you under my post, this will not work.